# Tensorflow data : apply function TO batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tf.data to iterate batch from large text corpus.

I want to apply a function to only subset of data(or to subset of batch), not one by one element.
Specifically, my data iterator yields
`query, reply` with batch. They are all positive pairs, so I just want to shuffle only subset of next batch(in this case, only "reply" batch") to generate random negatives.

For example, 
inputs:

`query1 reply1`

`query2 reply2`

`query3 reply3`

...

outputs:

- positive pairs: `query1 reply1` (same as inputs)
- negative pairs: `query1 replyN` (replies are random shuffled)

Of course it is possible to just shuffle text using python, but I want to make it efficient using tf.data because data size is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `queries` and `replies` as two Tensors. What you need is I think something like below what you can concatenate then with the original batch.

```
batch_size = 10
def reply_shuffle(queries, replies):
   shuffled_indices = tf.random_uniform(minval=0, maxval=batch_size+1, shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32)
   shuffled_replies = tf.gather_nd(replies, shuffled_indices) 
   return queries, shuffled_replies
```